# CSS not running until the page is refreshed manually

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-bind-html

The following code bind the sanitized html to a div

```
<div ng-bind-html="vm.html" ng-if="vm.isLoaded" ng-cloak></div>
```

The css classes inside the html content did not takes effect after displayed until I manually refresh the page. Did I miss out anything here?

vm.html content

```
<div class="pslider">
 <div class="slide"><img src="img1" /></div>
 <div class="slide"><img src="img2" /></div>
 <div class="slide"><img src="img3" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How / where are you loading CSS file?

Comment: @VivekAthalye The css files are located on index.html, which loaded once the app run

Comment: You may have a javascript error that is blocking the css from loading. Could you check the developer console for errors and post them if any? This could help illuminate the issue.

Comment: @Bonk I didn't see any errors from developer console.

Comment: After some investigation, I found that the javascript files are not loaded in the child view. I even tried lazy load the javascript but it still not working for me.